# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame' when using alibi package in Python

Tags: python

I'm hoping someone can help me. When I run the following setup I get the error below. It seems like the alibi package is causing it. The other posts related to this problem are either because of case sensitive spellings of 'DataFrame' or .py filenames.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)  # suppress deprecation messages
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from alibi.explainers import CounterFactualProto
```

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'